# Regarding two dimensional array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I have some problems using two dimensional array.

```
static const int PATTERNS[20][4];

static void init_PATTERN()
{
   // problem #1
   int (&patterns)[20][4] = const_cast<int[20][4]>(PATTERNS);  
   ...
}

extern void UsePattern(int a, const int** patterns, int patterns_size);

// problem #2
UsePattern(10, PATTERNS, sizeof(PATTERNS)/sizeof(PATTERNS[0]));
```

In the first statement, I need to cast the `const` off the two dimensional array `PATTERNS`. The reason for this is that the init function is called only once, and in the remaining code, `PATTERNS` is strictly read-only.

In the second statement, I need to pass `PATTERNS` array to the `int**` argument. Direct passing resulted a compile error.

---

I have solved the problem, just about the same time that @Andrey posted the answer.  Yes `int[][]` can't be casted to `int**`.

It can be casted to `int*` through `&(PATTERNS[0][0])`, and the function prototype must be modified with row size (the number of elements in a row). The array can be `const_cast` away with reference syntax.

Comment: Whats the compiler error? Care to share it ?

Comment: Why can't you use an initialiser list on the array?

Comment: Your "solved the problem" comment is just a bunch of hacks. None of them even remotely approach valid C++ programming, even if they might seem to "work" at the first sight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, there's no such thing as cast to array type (or to function type) in C++. Yet this is what you are trying to do. If you want to cast away constness from something, you have to cast to either pointer or reference type. In your case you have a reference on the receiving end of the cast, so the cast itself has to be to reference type as well

```
int (&patterns)[20][4] = const_cast<int (&)[20][4]>(PATTERNS);
```

Of course, as Bill already noted, casting away constness from a constant object (and then attempting to modify the object) leads to undefined behavior.

Secondly, a two-dimensional array cannot be passed anywhere as an `int **` pointer. If you want to pass your `PATTERNS` somewhere, you can pass it as `const int (&)[20][4]`, `const int (*)[20][4]`, `const int [][4]`, `const int (*)[4]` or something similar to that, but not as `int **`. Do a search on SO and/or read some [FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html) on arrays to understand why. This has been explained too many times to repeat it again.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare `PATTERNS` as const, the compiler may set it up in read-only memory.  You can't safely cast away const unless the item was originally declared without const.

I'm guessing that your compiler error was `cannot convert 'int (*)[4]' to 'int**' for argument '2' to 'void UsePattern(int, int**, int)'`?

Answer (score 1):

AndreyT's answer is perfect. I'd only like to add that I believe you would be better using a class that does the `init_PATTERN()` work in the constructor and overrides the `operator[]` to give readonly access to the array elements.

This, of course, assuming you can change the UsePattern function to get a reference to such class instead of a pointer to int array.

Answer (score 1):

C++ Arrays are complicated. You can't just throw them around and expect them to work like in some languages. The only way to initialize an array from another array is to navigate a **for** loop and copy each item individually. This goes doubly for two-dimensional arrays (meaning you'll need two **for** loops).

It seems like you're trying to make this more complicated than it needs to be. For instance, if the set of values you will be assigning to PATTERNS will be the same every time you run the program, you can initialize a two dimensional variable like this:

```
static const int foo[2][3] = {{11,12,13},{21,22,23}};
```

If the set of values assigned to PATTERNS varies from one execution to the next, then you should probably try to find a different way to approach the problem. I would probably wrap the data in a class, especially if your intention is to use similarly-sized two-dimensional arrays elsewhere in the code.